# missing or unreadable manifest.json chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, shortcut

I am having problems trying to create a simple personalized shortcut on the chrome's new tab page. Having no experience in the coding world, i followed the steps in this cool site.

http://www.howtogeek.com/169220/how-to-create-custom-chrome-web-app-shortcuts-for-your-favorite-websites/

The problem is that when loading the uncompressed extension, it mentions that it cannot find the manifest file or is unreadable.

```
{
“manifest_version”: 2,
“name”: “cnn“,
“description”: “cnn site“,
“version”: “1.0″,
“icons”: {
“128″: “128.png”
},
“app”: {
“urls”: [
"http://cnn.com/"

],
“launch”: {
“web_url”: “http://cnn.com/”
}
},
“permissions”: [
"unlimitedStorage",
"notifications"
]
}
```

Is it correct? Does it have anything to do with my chrome language set to portuguese? I have already created an 128.png image, and the notepad title is exacly "manifest.json"

Hope you can help, Cheers SRD

Answer (score 0):

Your quotation marks don't look correct.

Instead of using `“` and `”`, use `"`.